# Books on Patristics

Tags: church-history, church-fathers, books

What book(s) do you recommend on church history with emphasis on the church fathers? Would prefer something which is not biassed toward a given denomination or church, but an objective overview of the important personalities and their influence on the christian faith and culture. This meaning that I am really interested in their main dogmatic views and theological contributions.

Even if this seems to be a very broad topic and field, could you recommend me the book(s) that were helpful for you and your understanding on this?

I have not studied church history so far, and have a very basic knowledge, but I am becoming more and more interested about it and would like to study it in more detail. I also think, that this is very important for my general knowledge and also my faith.

(In the community I have been raised, there was not so much accent on Church History in general).

Comment: Sorry, but we don't really do book recommendations here. But one idea for you is to look up a bunch of the course descriptions from theological colleges and see what textbooks they say are recommended or required.

Comment: @curiousdannii oh, I didn't know that. Sorry, maybe I mistakenly overlooked the forum rules and suggestions, I only joined today. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Ancient-Testaments-Patriarchs-Autobiographies-Scrolls/dp/1975887743/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?keywords=ken+johnson+books&qid=1581914565&sprefix=ken+johns&sr=8-5
Check out Ken Johnson if you’re interested in simpler reading.

Comment: This [suggested reading list](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/justin-taylor/reading-the-church-fathers-a-beginners-guide/) looks promising.  I would start with the 2 books by [Wilken](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0300105983/thegospcoal-20)  and [Chadwick](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0140231994/thegospcoal-20) by professional historian instead of "biased" theologians to provide the backbone for further study.

Comment: @Autodidact thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: @GratefulDisciple thanks for the recommendation, I will look into that!

Comment: You can find the complete set of Philip Schaff's *Ante-Nicene* and *Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers* online at CCEL or New Advent.  You could start with [*Volume 1:  The Apostolic Fathers with Justin Martyr and Ireneus*](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01/anf01.i.html).  Each section begins with a decent, fairly objective overview of the author (although the editors were prominent Protestants).  The only caveat is that many of the writers included in the series were/are not recognized as true Church Fathers by everyone, but Vol 1 is fairly safe.

Answer (score 3):

[Bardenhewer's "Patrology"](https://archive.org/details/patrologythelive00obaruoft) is in my opinion the best introduction to the Church Fathers that is freely available online. It's dense and long but gives a complete account of all the known writers, their works, and significance.

Also useful are [Tixeront's "Manual of Patrology"](https://archive.org/details/ahandbookpatrol00tixegoog) and [Stearns' "Manual of Patrology"](https://archive.org/details/manualofpatrolog00steauoft).

You might also find useful [Fortescue's "The Greek Fathers"](https://archive.org/details/TheGreekFathers). Some of the information here may be slightly dated, but these books are all largely accurate and Bardenhewer is comprehensive.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to break up the text a little better, but I noticed that you duplicated one of the references. If this is my error, feel free to roll back the edit. And thank you for your contributions.